# How to resolve this error? Included the merged manifest errors info

Tags: android, android-manifest

> Error: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. >
>   Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs Merged Manifest
>   Error Info: Merging Errors: Error: Attribute
>   provider#android.support.v4.content.FileProvider@authorities
>   value=(es.guiguegon.gallerymodule.provider) from
>   AndroidManifest.xml:20:13-70 is also present at
>   AndroidManifest.xml:15:13-80
>   value=(com.example.parij.myschoolcomm.easyphotopicker.fileprovider).
>   Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:authorities"' to 
>   element at AndroidManifest.xml:18:9-29:20 to override. app main
>   manifest (this file), line 19 Error: Attribute
>   meta-data#android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS@resource
>   value=(@xml/provider_paths) from AndroidManifest.xml:26:17-55 is also
>   present at AndroidManifest.xml:22:17-50 value=(@xml/filepaths).
>   Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:resource"' to 
>   element at AndroidManifest.xml to override. app main manifest (this
>   file), line 25

Here's my Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    package="com.example.parij.myschoolcomm"
    android:label="Impetus-Kids"
    tools:replace="android:allowBackup,icon,theme,label,name,resource">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!--         android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" -->
    <application
        android:name=".ImpetusKids"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/impetusimg"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:replace="android:label"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Main4Activity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="        Dashboard"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Main5Activity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".HomeWorkActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".TimetableActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ReqLeaveActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".EmergencyActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".AuthorizedPersonActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SyllabusCoverage"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".AnnouncementActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".parentmain"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_parentmain"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

        <activity
            android:name=".fragment2_parentmain"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".fragment3_parentmain"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".admindashboard"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="Dashboard"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".adminparent"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".adminchild"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ResetPassword"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".adminemergency"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".adminauthorized"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Logout"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".parentwindow"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".childdetailswindow"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustPan" />

        <activity
            android:name=".emergencywindow"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".authorizedwindow"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".daycaredashboard"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".monday"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".tuesday"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".wednesday"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".thursday"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".friday"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".saturday"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".syllabusadmin"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".AdminHomeWork"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".announcementadmin"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustPan" />

        <activity
            android:name=".announcementuser"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".tempParentRegistration"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".reqleaveadmin"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustPan" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Weeklymenu"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".LiveFeed"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".daycarechild"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".daycaretimetable"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".daycare_parentmain"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Memories"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ThemeAdmin"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ThemeUser"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Timetable_jrandsrkg"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Timetable_nursery"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Timetable_playgroup"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".userfeedback"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity android:name=".MemoriesUser"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Build Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android
{
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.parij.myschoolcomm"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 16
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled = true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
}
 }

 dependencies {
//implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})



compile 'com.libRG:customtextview:1.2'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
compile 'cn.jzvd:jiaozivideoplayer:6.2.3'
compile 'com.ramotion.foldingcell:folding-cell:1.2.1'
compile 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
compile 'com.github.jkwiecien:EasyImage:1.3.1'
compile 'com.github.shts:StoriesProgressView:2.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
compile 'com.github.mzelzoghbi:zgallery:0.3'
compile 'es.guiguegon:gallerymodule:1.3.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Looks like the error is pretty self-explanatory. Your `tools:replace` attributes should have values mentioned. - `tools:replace="android:allowBackup,icon,theme,label,name,resource,android:authorities,android:resource"`

Comment: @ReazMurshed , tried it ,didn't work

Comment: I would also suggest to remove the `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` and the `tools:replace="android:allowBackup,icon,theme,label,name,resource"` attributes. Why are they necessary?

Comment: did you merge with an existing branch of git ??

Comment: @SantanuSur No.